# SQL Developer Query Result

Tags: sql, oracle

error:

[image: error]

How to clear the table?

Comment: You are inserting six rows. I don't see what you're talking about?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to show 6 rows in query result?

Comment: Maybe you have a trigger which duplicates the lines during insertion.

Comment: How can I fix that? @Meninx-メネンックス

Comment: Try running this query: `select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'Personel'` and tell me if it gives you lines ?

Comment: It didn't work. Every time I "Run Script" it adds another 6 rows. Is there any way to reset it? @Meninx-メネンックス

Comment: the query above did it give you lines or not ?

Comment: It didn't add lines but it did when I clicked run script

Comment: show me the result of this  query please: `select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'Personel'` ?

Comment: I'm adding it to the question @Meninx-メネンックス

Comment: So the issue is not related to triggers !

Comment: I think you had run the insertion queries twice that's why you got it duplicated as you do not have a primary key set.

Comment: Regarding triggers, you are looking for triggers `where table = 'Personel'` but it should be `'PERSONEL'` (which maybe should be [PERSONNEL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personnel) anyway). The dictionary stores names in uppercase.

Comment: Please, do not use images , which might be unreachable due to firewalls for some endusers, for sample data or queries. Moreover, the images here are not being magnified. Unable to see them. Prefer text data as being easily manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every time** you run the script, it adds new set of rows to the table and duplicates them.

If you want to stop it, then don't run the script multiple times (obviously).

In order to **reset** the whole thing, a simple option is to delete everything and re-insert those rows:

```
truncate table personel;
insert into personel values ... <your INSERT statements go here>
```

In order to **prevent** it to happen, if e.g. `pno` column is unique, create a unique/primary key on it. e.g.

```
create table personel (pno   varchar2(5) primary key,
                       fname varchar2(15), 
                       ...
                      );
```

Note that I used `varchar2`, and so should you (as Oracle recommends it).

As of using **mixed case**, Oracle is - by default - case insensitive unless you enclose table name into double quotes. As you didn't do it, your table is stored (into the *data dictionary*) in upper case, so - checking that *possible trigger* on the table can't return anything, i.e. :

```
No : select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'Personel';
Yes: select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'PERSONEL';
```

Comment: What does that mean? What is "clearing script" supposed to do?

Comment: I accidentally kept adding new rows by clicking run script. How can I delete those rows?

Comment: Re-read the 3rd sentence in my answer and code that follows.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand it. I put all my insert values there but it did nothing. I don't think I did it right.

Comment: As there are just too many rows there, first delete them (which means that you'll have an empty table). Then run those INSERT statements, but **only once**. I suggest you re-read everything I wrote, this time try to actually *understand* what I was saying. If that's not enough, read again. And again. I've said mostly everything I meant to say and there's no point in repeating it.